# my css, js and imgs files are not comming in static folder

Tags: python, css, django, django-views, django-templates

After running the following command for the Django project:

**python manage.py collectstatic**

Some other CSS files are generated, but the following CSS files "that exist in my template folder" are not coming into a static generated folder.
[image]

[image: static settings]

When I manually copy-paste these files after the command then it works on local to load, but on production upon deployment to Heroku, it again runs collecstatic command which overwrites those files and then it doesn't load.

I also have disabled collect static upon deploying the project to Heroku to prevent overwriting then again it does not load CSS files from the static folder.

Please, does anyone, know how I could deal with it? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should keep static files under appname/static folder not in appname/templates. Collectstatic copy files from appname/static only

Comment: Thanks Waldemar! You saved my time, actually I was thinking it will copy from the template folder, but according to you initial static folder should be made in appname/static. and it worked.